# No change in database when I have checked in sqliteBrowser

Tags: iphone, ios8, sqlite, swift2

I am using sqlite3 with fmdb and xcode6.1 (swift).

In my application, need to update some data from db.
It’s updated.
But when I have  checked in sqliteBrowser ,it didn’t update.(that sqlite file is in my project folder).

Is it normal ??
or Something wrong??

I am confused because when I restart my app, it's really updated.(not updated only when I have checked db with sqliteBrowser)

```
 var database:FMDatabase!
        let resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL!.absoluteString
        let dbPath = resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("mydbname.sqlite")
        let dbTest = FMDatabase(path: dbPath)

if (!dbTest.open()) {
            println("Could not open database at \(dbPath).")
        } else {
            println("open database at \(dbPath).")

            var sql = "UPDATE tblEducation SET edu_fav = 0"
            let results = dbTest.executeUpdate(sql, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if results {
                println("Success Update")
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run sql file from your project and make changes with it. For that App create a sqlite file to your project folder and do changes with it only. So if you want to see changes done in simulator than check into project directory and database file.

Comment: Thanks alot.  U mean i can check like this directory (/Users/*****/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/81C5B3CA-1974-4A78-8***-1F194D680FB8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BECA6920-39AA-4A0C-B592-4FA08FDFC***/MySample.app/mydbname.sqlite).  If i am wrong plz correct me @Esha

Comment: yes. u check that sqlite file and the changes you do the database from the code will be reflected from there only.